# JTextField increase size to the top

Tags: jtextfield

I have a form, how do i make the text fileld to increase its size to the top not bottom of the form [form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wG9xW.png)

[image]

```
 txfWin.setSize(30,reel.getNumberOfWins()+reel.getNumberOfWins()*10);
```

Comment: can you post some code, so I could understand what I'm looking at?

Comment: updated my post with code

Comment: Is the colored thing a textfield? Is that the problem?

Comment: yes instead of extending its size to the top it goes to bottom

Comment: you have to start loving GridBagLayout :) Just create a grid with 6 elements. Top row with three and bottom one with three as well. Then, put stuff there. Make bottom row as fixed. You can find nice tutorial here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html

Comment: Why use a textfield as a bar? Use a rectangle..?

Comment: Here is a [usage](http://blue-walrus.com/2014/03/bar-chart-in-java-swing/) of rectangle.